# nodejs - failing to install contextify via npm

Tags: node.js, npm

Getting errors regarding "node-gyp rebuild" but can't seem to figure out why?

Full error: http://pastebin.com/HJ4z6tie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, this links and solutions will be useful for you:

1) https://github.com/hideo55/node-murmurhash3/issues/4

Problem:

> When I run the command `sudo npm link` your NPM is failing.

Solution:

> when I use `--unsafe-perm=true` this NPM works.

2) https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#permission-error

> Permission Error
>
> npm ERR! code EPERM
>
> npm ERR! code EACCES
>
> ```
> Fix the permissions of your cache with sudo chown -R $(whoami) "$HOME/.npm".
> Try again with sudo. e.g. sudo npm install express -g. (You'll probably need to fix cache permissions afterwards, as above).
> Reinstall node so it doesn't require sudo.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The `EACCES` error code means that the process does not have permissions to read/write in the target directory/file. As is common with package managers, this usualy means the module could not be installed to target directory.

This may be fixed by running the command as super user (`sudo ...`), but preferrably you would just fix the file permissions so that the account that runs the command has necessary permissions to the target directory.

As a side-note, the `EACCES` error comes from the great Linux itself - see the [list of other error codes](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) (or run `man errno`) one might encounter.

Comment: Hi, the command is being ran using super user: "sudo npm install --save email-templates" and has been attempted directly as root too.  No cigar :-(

Comment: Try to run the `npm install` command with `--verbose` flag and see if you can learn something useful from the detailed logs...

Answer (score 0):

Define environment variable NODE_PATH as such :

```
export NODE_PARENT=${HOME}/node-v0.12.0
export PATH=${NODE_PARENT}/bin:${PATH}  # so executables are found
export NODE_PATH=${NODE_PARENT}/lib/node_modules # so node can find modules

./configure   --prefix=${NODE_PARENT}
```

do this when installing Node from source ... which gives you node and npm
and will avoid all such permission errors ... then install modules as yourself ... no need for root

```
npm install -g some-global-module
```